# open chrome extension window by right-clicking instead of extension icon of browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am going to open the chrome extension window by clicking the mouse right button on active web page instead of extension icon of browser.

It is possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the contextMenus API : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus

Examples :

1. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/contextMenus/basic.zip
2. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/contextMenus/event_page.zip

Comment: The chrome extension has to open when I click the mouse right button on any active web page

Comment: I do not think this is possible. The contextMenu is to me the best option then (You need two clicks: right click, then select your extension).
What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You can inject a content script that listens to `mousedown`, checks if the right button was clicked, then display a normal DOM popup, not the extension popup as it's impossible.

Comment: I want like following

Comment: when i take right-click on any active web page, the menu item that has the label "chrome extension menu" will be shown on the popup menu , and then when we click the menu. and the chrome extension window will be shown.

Comment: how do I have to do?

Comment: That is using `chrome.contextMenus`. Though again you won't be able to open the popup window without a user clicking the popup icon.

Comment: You can't use the icon popup, but you can use tabs.create or windows.create.

Comment: @nicovank , When user right clicks "on the extension's icon"(and not on the active web page), is it possible to add an item there that opens the extension's popup? (Yes, I want to add an extra step because I need left clicking on the extension to do something else.)